# Support for arm apk on android emulator built for X86

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created an android emulator using Android Studio for X86 cpu arch(CPU/ABI = X86_64) since it is very much faster on my mac or linux machines which are X86.

However I need to install an arm7 apk on it and it fails because the emulator is built for x86 with this error as expected.

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

I don't have the source code to recompile the apk for X86 arch. In Genymotion we use an ARM translator and it works fine, however we are restricted to android AVD emulator for this specific use case.

Is there anything similar(ARM Translator) for the x86 AVD Android Emulators as well? I don't want to build the emulator for arm7 because it is 10x slower on my mac/linux machines.

Thanks very much.